# Issue with type mismatch between Arraylist and Object in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

I have a code like the below:

```
ArrayList<String> first_name = new ArrayList<String>();
Object result = request.getAttribute("first_name");  
first_name = (ArrayList<String>) result;
```

the thing is request.getAttribute must be an Object.
I try to cast it so that it become ArrayList.
however it returns java.lang.NullPointerException

can anyone solve the problem please.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does it throw a NPE? What is the type of `request`?

Comment: Note: You can write `ArrayList<String> first_name = new ArrayList<>();` (The Diamond).

Comment: ...provided you're using *Java 7 or above*.

Comment: I'm sure this is not the only code. Because if it is, then it really doesn't make sense to add it to request and retrieve it from that, immediately. I'm assuming that this code spans over multiple classes.

Comment: Are you dispatching the request or not ?

Answer (score 2):

The only line of code that can throw a NullPointerException here is the second one and only when `request` is null. The third line (the cast) cannot throw an NPE, as you can cast `null` to `ArrayList<String>` anytime.

So check if `request` has a value.

Comment: IMHO, `request`  cannot be null in a jsp. OP facing a weird issue or he fails to explain. +1.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - Why can't that be null? Infact, that is the only possibility.

Comment: @R.J Agreed. But someone needs to request that jsp. That is what came in my mind. Yes. in the code shown ,that is the only possibility. :(

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - Its upto to the OP. If the OP wants a proper answer, they need to show more code. Otherwise, there is nothing much we can do(definitely not keep asking for more code).

Comment: @R.J Well said. Great questions gets Great answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You could surround your code by a try-catch block. Then handle the request when retrieving null or simply throw NullPointerException.